# Using System.Uri with Get-ChildItem

Tags: powershell

1. I need to produce a list of files that have been changed in the last seven days. To the best of my knowledge, this is a way to do it:

   ```
   Get-ChildItem | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)}
   ```
2. I want to "catch" only the basic directory that the files are located in. For example, if a file is located in the path "c:\dir1\dir2\dir3", I want to catch only the "dir1" directory (I don't need the root path). To the best of my knowledge, this is a way to do it:

   ```
   ([System.Uri]"c:\dir1\dir2\dir3").segments[2]
   ```
3. The problem is that I don't understand how to combine the previous processes. How do I produce a list of the relevant directories (as described in item no. 2) that is based on the results of the process that is described in item no. 1.
4. I guess it won't surprise you that even if we would achieve what I'm trying to do (as described in item no. 3), we would get a lot of duplicate results.

Even when I tried to achieve only what is described in item no. 1, and tried to remove duplicates, it didn't work as expected.

I used the following commands (please notice the `Get-Unique` cmdlet):

```
Get-ChildItem | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} |
  select directory | Get-Unique | Out-GridView
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 3) , use `ForEach-Object` in the pipeline to process each element (which is represented by `$_`):

```psh
Get-ChildItem | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} | ForEach-Object { ([System.Uri]$_.FullName).segments[2] } | Get-Unique | Out-Gridview
```

Comment: When I tried to run this, I got the following error in the PowerShell console:

Cannot convert the "bla" value of type "System.IO.DirectoryInfo" to type "System.Uri".
At line:1 char:88
+ ... AddDays(-7)} | ForEach-Object { ([System.Uri]$_).segments[2] } | Out ...
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException

Comment: I verified that when I try to cast and segment a specific file, everything is alright. The error mentioned above appears only the operations mentioned above are being done for each object in the pipeline.

Comment: @kurkum did you try the edited version? It works for me.

Comment: Thanks briantist, the edited version solves item no. 3 in my question. However, the problem with item no. 4 still presists.

None of the following methods works, and there are still duplicate results:
1) Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} | ForEach-Object { [string](([System.Uri]$_.FullName).segments[2].trim("/")) } | Get-Unique | Out-Gridview

2) Get-ChildItem -recurse | Where{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} | ForEach-Object { ([string]$_.FullName).split("\")[2] } | out-gridview

Comment: It seems the get-unique does not handle the results as an actual strings, since it does not remove all the duplicate.

When using the -recurse parameter, one of the results is a subfolder name which is taken from the path of this specific folder, and if there is a file or directory in this subfolder, there would be other results which would be the same, but are taken from a path that refer to the subfolder of this subfolder.

In other words, "c:\dir1" and "c:\dir1\dir2" would produce the same result, which is "dir1". For some reason, get-unique does not identify these results as duplicate.

Comment: @kurkum You didn't mention using `-Recurse` at all. Additionally, you can use this answer as a starting point to figure out the next step, and edit your question with what you've tried.